# jquery toggle close other opened divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I have an issue with using toggle where i need to close other divs that are already opened, so only the div you click on is open at one time, but still toggles.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(".flyout").hide();
        $(".flyout").siblings("span").click(function () {
            $(this).siblings(".flyout").toggle(500);
        });
    });
</script>  

<ul>
<li ><span id="europe"></span>Europe
<div class="flyout">
<ul>
<li>item 1</li>
</ul>
</div>
</li>

<li ><span id="europe"></span>Asia
<div class="flyout">
<ul>
<li>item 1</li>
</ul>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
```

Any ideas on what I can add in to get the click function to close every other div class="flyout" except the one its on?

have a look at http://www.footballadvisor.net/map/ to see the issue

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Check this, please:

http://jsfiddle.net/MbTRD/1/

```
$(function () {
    $(".flyout").hide();
    $(".flyout").siblings("span").click(function () {
        $(this).siblings(".flyout").toggle(500);
    });
});
```

​

Comment: thats really cool, its my exact markup though so doesnt fix the problem?

Comment: yes your correct markup is 

<ul>
<li ><span id="europe">Europe</span>
<div class="flyout">
<ul>
<li>item 1</li>
</ul>
</div>
</li>

<li ><span id="europe">Asia</span>
<div class="flyout">
<ul>
<li>item 1</li>
</ul>
</div>
</li>
</ul>

Comment: Ive put this up so you can see it working www.footballadvisor.net/map basically if i click on an arrow to show the div, I need it to close all other open div class="flyout"

Comment: that is so so close, the only issue is when you click a link to close the toggle it closes it and then opens it again :( thanks for your time on this :)

Answer (score 1):

The name of the country should be inside the span if you want to catch the click event.
The following close everything except the element you clicked :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(function () {
         $(".flyout").hide();
         $(".flyout").siblings("span").click(function () {
             $(".flyout").hide();
             $(this).siblings(".flyout").toggle(500);
         });
     });
</script>  

<ul>
<li ><span id="europe">Europe</span>
<div class="flyout">
<ul>
<li>item 1</li>
</ul>
</div>
</li>

<li ><span id="europe">Asia</span>
<div class="flyout">
<ul>
<li>item 1</li>
</ul>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Ive put this up so you can see it working http://www.footballadvisor.net/map/

basically if i click on an arrow to show the div, I need it to close all other open div class="flyout"

Comment: Give a try to the snippet in my response.

Comment: thanks, i have tried this one prior and it just closes and reopens the div on toggle :(

Answer (score 1):

check this http://jsfiddle.net/MbTRD/5/ i hope this will helpful for you

Answer (score 0):

Here an improvement to your jQuery: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/toroncino/MbTRD/14/)

```
    $(function () {
        $(".flyout").siblings("span").click(function () {
            $(".flyout").slideUp(200, function() {
                $(this).siblings(".flyout").toggle(500);
            });
            $(this).siblings(".flyout").toggle(500);
        });
    });
```